# Caling a web API through a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-web-api

I want to retrieve the financial data of apple company from a data provider "intrinio"

I am pretty good at nodejs so i was able to write the code and retrieve the data into the console.log using nodejs. The code is as follows -

```
var https = require("https");
var username = "****";
var password = "****";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ':' + 
password).toString('base64');

var request = https.request({
method: "GET",
host: "api.intrinio.com",
path: "/companies?ticker=AAPL",
headers: {
    "Authorization": auth
 }
 }, function(response) {
 var json = "";
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    json += chunk;
 });
 response.on('end', function() {
    var company = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(company);
 });
});

request.end();
```

My question here is how do i write this code in a javascript(without node) function and call the javascript function upon a button click and display the data on a html page. Please help me out with this.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You can use XMLHttpRequest, but be fully aware that bringing this to the frontend side of a webpage will cause your username/password to be exposed in some way.

Comment: @ReyHaynes you could route the request through a server side (node, php, whatever), where you store the password. Then use XMLHttpReqest against your own api.

Comment: @OnklMaps True...but the question states that he wants to do it basically from the frontend, without node itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you go with Ajax requests to do so. Just use the POST method and fetch the data.

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "https://api.intrinio.com/companies?ticker=AAPL",  
            header: auth,  
            success: function(dataString) {
                console.log(dataString); 
            }  
        });
```

Comment: no reason to use jQuery here. He also never asked about using POST

Answer (score 0):

> You can use JavaScript XMLHttpRequest

[Visit this link to see more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)

OR You can use below promise based function of the same -

```
var callAPI = function(type, url, payload) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open(type, url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authToken);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
            resolve({
                status : this.status,
                data : JSON.parse(this.responseText)
            });
        }
    };
    if(type.toLowerCase() === 'post'){
        xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payload));
    }else{
        xhttp.send();
    }
});
}
```